# In Android Studio 3.0.1 has something changed in git, after I push online one project, I cannot checkout

Tags: git, android-studio, gitignore

I have a problem with git (when Android Studio is updated to version 3.0.1).

I use git integration like always I use. I create a repository, commit changes on this and push in Git repository online (like GitLab or BitBucket). 
But now I have a problem when I try to do a checkout from Version Control if I check out one project (that I pushed before without a problem) into another PC "go down" with one problem! There is no run configurator (image below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSic.png)

So I don't know how to solve this problem, I am not very expert, I never touched `.gitignore` file. I always use Android Studio system to do that operation! 
please, if somebody can help in explaining me the situation, it is not very clear to me.

Comment: If you are sure that you added root of VCS try to invalidate cache and restart file -> Invalidate caches / restart

Comment: yes i enter entire project folder! the problem start when android studio is update to version 3.0.1... :(